# Problem binding View to ViewModel with DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have recently started trying to make sense of MVVM and am using the MvvmFoundation classes. I am attempting to use a DataTemplate for a View Model class to display the View. The XAML code is below: TVM is a property of type TrackViewModel.

The TrackView placed in the Stack panel using a DataContext displays correctly. The content control version renders as an empty TrackViewModel.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type vm:TrackViewModel}" >
        <v:TrackView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Width="200" Height="50" Content="{Binding Path=TVM, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <v:TrackView DataContext="{Binding TVM}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

It seems that I havent set up a link between the TrackView in the DataTemplate and the instansiated TrackViewModel, TVM. Consequently the PropertyChangedEventHandler's for TrackViewModel show up as null in the non-working case but are fine when I directly set the Datacontext.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

The TrackView XAML is as below:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:TrackViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="barBackgroundBrush"  StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" Opacity="0.7">
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Blue"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="Aquamarine"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Blue"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="barTrackingBrush"  StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" Opacity="0.7">
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Orange"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="OrangeRed"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Orange"/>

    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="RegionDataTemplate" >
        <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="3" Background="{StaticResource barTrackingBrush}" 
                    Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}"
                    Width="{Binding Path=Duration}">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Path=StartFrame}"/>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
       <UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:TrackViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Regions, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RegionDataTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="{StaticResource barBackgroundBrush}" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Panel}}}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are setting the `DataContext` in the `UserControl` XAML, it won't be inherited in the `ContentControl` case.  In the second case, you are setting it explicitly, which will override when it is set in the `UserControl` declaration.  Deleting this will allow the `UserControl` to inherit the `DataContext` of the `ContentControl`, which will be the Content that you set in the `Binding`.

Comment: Thats brilliant, many thanks. Defeated by my own testing code! 
Feels a little counterintuitive that it wouldn't be over ridden but I understand why. Thanks again